# How to pass a list variable which contains column names of particular table to django model values() in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, django-models, django-rest-framework

Consider the list as below :
`listofcol = ['col1','col2','col3']`
Django Model Example:
`model.tablename.objects.values(listofcol).filter()`

I would like to fetch the list of columns from the variable `listofcol` and tried as mentioned in the *Django Model Example* and getting the error message as `'list' object has no attribute 'split'`.
In Brief, the table contains some 50+ columns. The selected columns will be stored in `listofcol` variable(columns changes periodically) which I need to fetch through Django model. 
Is there any way to fetch so..?

Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) I assume you need to unpack that list, like this:

```
model.tablename.objects.values(*listofcol).filter()
```

Just assumption, please tell if works :)